# How to fix Excel coding which return #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in Excel that return a value based on the string on the other column. For instance, Column A contains string:

```
"(1) Missing Data For 1 Runs..(20%)"
```

and in the column B is: `"20"`. The formula in the column B is:

```
 "=IF(ISBLANK(N14),"",(MID(RIGHT(N14,9),SEARCH("(",RIGHT(N14,9))+1,SEARCH(")",RIGHT(N14,9))-SEARCH("(",RIGHT(N14,9))-1)+0)*100)".
```

This formula works fine with the similar string with different percentage, such as 30%, 25%, etc, including there is no string or value in Column A, which return empty value in column B.

However, there is other string exist in column A, such as

```
"(2) This spare part underwent repairs.."
```

in which the formula returns `#VALUE` in column B. Also, there is other string which combines both string, such as

```
"(1) Missing Data For 1 Runs..(17%) 
(2) This spare part underwent repairs ..",
```

in which returns `#VALUE` as well in Column B.

What is the formula that returns the percentage number in the other column, in this case?

Comment: Quite hard to understand from the bits of information, but are you simply trying to eliminate the errors ? like this ?  
`=IFERROR((MID(RIGHT(N14,9),SEARCH("(",RIGHT(N14,9))+1,SEARCH(")",RIGHT(N14,9))-SEARCH("(",RIGHT(N14,9))-1)+0)*100,"") `

Comment: Not to eliminate the errors, but to return a percentage value from a column to another column. So, in the formula I mentioned above there are strings in Column N in different rows, such as:

`(1) Missing Data For 1 Runs..(17%) `

`(2) This spare part underwent repairs..`

`(1) Missing Data For 1 Runs..(17%) (2) This spare part underwent repairs..`

or blank

So, I want to take only the value at the front of percentage.

Comment: Just some precision, a) is there always only one percentage per string and b) ist the percentage always 2-digit ?

Comment: a) yes, there is only one percentage per string. However, not all rows have percentage, sometimes they are blank, and sometimes other string with no percentage values in it, just a statement string

b)no, percentage can be from 1 to 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your feedback, if there is only on percentage per cell, use the "%" as anchor for your search (not the bracket as you did). Try following

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A13,SEARCH("%",A13)-2,2)),IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A13,SEARCH("%",A13)-1,1)),""))
```

how it works

```
VALUE(MID(A13,SEARCH("%",A13)-2,2))
```

will look for all instances where percentages have 2 digits and if so return 2 digits as a value, everything else throws an error and the second part applies. Second part

```
IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A13,SEARCH("%",A13)-1,1)),"")
```

will look for all intances with one digit percentages and returns this one digit as a value. Everything else throws an error which returns a blank.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the help!